# Cordova plugin Fingerprint All-In-One

Tags: javascript, cordova, plugins, cordova-plugins, fingerprint

I'm using the Fingerprint All-In-One, and I do not understand how to pick up the enrolled fingerprint. How to get already enrolled fingerprint?

https://github.com/mjwheatley/cordova-plugin-android-fingerprint-auth

```js
document.addEventListener('deviceready', Pronto, false);

function Pronto() {
  alert("Carregado!");
  Fingerprint.isAvailable(isAvailableSuccess, isAvailableError);

  function isAvailableSuccess() {
    document.querySelector(".btn_finger").style.display = "block"
  }

  function isAvailableError(message) {
    alert(message);
  }
}

document.querySelector(".btn_finger").addEventListener("click", pronto1);

function pronto1() {
  Fingerprint.show({
    clientId: 'Fingerprint-Demo',
    clientSecret: 'password', //Only necessary for Android
    disableBackup: true, //Only for Android(optional)
  }, successCallback, errorCallback);

  function successCallback(result) {
    alert("Cadastrado");
  }

  function errorCallback(err) {
    alert("Authentication invalid " + err);
  };
}

alert(fingerid);
```

Comment: I dont think you can pick up the fingerprint as is android security regulations would not allow that

Comment: But how could I know if his digital is already registered?

Comment: judging from the code example (and my knowledge of how android works) Id say if you get a success callback its registered and if you get an errorCallback its not oO

Comment: Make sense, i gonna try,THANKS!